# ion_auth is not working on host (CI 2.1.3 + MX HMVC + Ion_auth 2.5.2)

Tags: php, codeigniter, ion-auth, codeigniter-hmvc

I developed a site using Codeigniter 2.1.3 + MX HMVC + ion_auth 2.5.2. its work fine in local server (xampp) but when i upload it to the hosting site its not working & surprisingly so error also.

I was autoload ion_auth but now i remove ion_auth from autoload. now when i try to load mysite/auth its empty. i tried this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6352980/using-ion-auth-as-a-separate-module-in-the-hmvc-structure) but sitll no luck .

Please someone help me. . i stuck in this last two days.

My hosting site is ([iiuc.ac.bd/qsis](http://www.iiuc.ac.bd/qsis)) frontend is ok but when i try to login is empty...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First make sure display_errors is on in your php.ini and make sure you have error_reporting set to the correct level.