# How to load ion auth model in codeigniter HMVC

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3, ion-auth

I am using the ion auth library for the CodeIgniter HMVC, I have copied all files from ion auth library to main CodeIgniter files but the controller, model, and views files copy to module directory Now it's showing me this error.

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Undefined property: Auth::$ion_auth_model
>
> Filename: libraries/Ion_auth.php
>
> Line Number: 122
>
> Backtrace:
>
> File: /opt/lampp/htdocs/CI_Hmvc/application/libraries/Ion_auth.php
>   Line: 122 Function: _error_handler
>
> File: /opt/lampp/htdocs/CI_Hmvc/application/libraries/Ion_auth.php
>   Line: 70 Function: __get
>
> File: /opt/lampp/htdocs/CI_Hmvc/application/third_party/MX/Loader.php
>   Line: 173 Function: _ci_load_library
>
> File: /opt/lampp/htdocs/CI_Hmvc/application/third_party/MX/Loader.php
>   Line: 192 Function: library
>
> File: /opt/lampp/htdocs/CI_Hmvc/application/third_party/MX/Loader.php
>   Line: 153 Function: libraries
>
> File:
>   /opt/lampp/htdocs/CI_Hmvc/application/modules/home/controllers/Auth.php
>   Line: 9 Function: library
>
> File: /opt/lampp/htdocs/CI_Hmvc/index.php Line: 315 Function:
>   require_once

could anybody tell me how to load the model, when I work as modules?

Comment: post the constructor for `libraries/ion_auth.php`

Comment: Can you tell me where you kept `ion_auth_model` means in which folder

Comment: I have keep Ion_auth_model in module dir model but ion_auth_model is load in library ion_auth.php that's why is showing error in library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the problem is that the library is not finding the model. Check inside ion auth library construct. Look for the line where it says

```
   $this->load->model('ion_auth_model').
```

It should be line 122 since that's where the error is ocurring. In here you need to prefix the module name - where you have the `ion_auth_model` - to the model path so the loader class knows where to find it.

In your case if the module's name is directory, then 'directory/ion_auth_model'.

Check this solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/7003180/5785088, point 10, last item. Hope it helps.