# Call to undefined method MY_Loader::_ci_load_class()

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-3, ion-auth

Setup CodeIgniter and CI HMVC MX Library successfully but when setup Ion auth after installed CI HMVC MX Library, Got below error.

```
An uncaught Exception was encountered
Type: Error

Message: Call to undefined method MY_Loader::_ci_load_class()

Filename: D:\xampp\htdocs\ci21\application\libraries\MX\Loader.php

Line Number: 158
```

Has anyone face this error?

Answer (score 0):

Handy information to help you along would be letting people know what versions you have.

Codeigniter version ?
HMVC version ?
Ion Auth version ?

That being said, if you follow along with the answers posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6352980/using-ion-auth-as-a-separate-module-in-the-hmvc-structure/7003180#7003180) ( on another StackOverflow question ) you should get everything up and running fine.